# Energy-momentum tensor for the k-essence theory

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

could anyone please explain or show some simple steps how using matter action:
$S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} L(X, \phi)$, where $X = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \phi \nabla_\nu \phi$

We can derive energy-momentum tensor:
$T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}$

I understand that we should take variation of action $\delta S$ with respect to $g^{\mu \nu}$ , but I don't understand how to fit X into $L(X, \phi)$
Can I just put instead  of $L(X, \phi)$, $X = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \phi \nabla_\nu \phi$, into action and take variation or there is anything more in the process ?
Am I wrong about my variant of just putting X into action ?

Comment: Yes, you can't just put in $X$ instead. Hint: $\delta L(X) = \delta X L'(X)$

Comment: So if we talk about $ L(X, \phi)$ it will be: $\delta L(X, \phi) = \delta X L(X, \phi) + \delta \phi L(X, \phi)$?

Comment: You're missing the derivatives of $L$ (that's what the prime denotes). I'll write this explicitly in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the variations you need to use the following relation
$$\delta L (X, \Phi) = \delta X \frac{\partial L(X,\Phi)}{\partial X} + \delta \Phi \frac{\partial L(X,\Phi)}{\partial \Phi} \ ,$$
which is just a general fact for derivatives/variations of functions.

The variations with respect to the metric will only include the first term on the RHS - the other term will contribute to the $\Phi$ equations of motion.

Comment: Eletie, thank you very much for answering my question